# Httpurlconnection with samsung s5

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, galaxy, s5

I found an issue in Samsung S5 with using HTTPURLCONNECTION may be I'm doing wrong but if any one have an idea kindly guide me.

Here is my code :

```
URL urls = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urls.openConnection();

connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("x-os-application-token", Constants.APPLICATION_TOKEN);

connection.setConnectTimeout(900000);
connection.setReadTimeout(150000);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);


DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
        connection.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(json);
wr.flush();
wr.close();


int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Now using this code if I manually Internet disconnect (WI_FI OFF) then other device (e.g. Nexus 5 and Samsung Galaxy Note 3) give me response immediate but In Samsung S5 it respond me after **connection.setReadTimeout(150000)** ??? 2.5 minutes

Comment: your read time out is too much can't you set it to 5 seconds?

Comment: **give me response immediate**. what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Raghunandan "your read time out is too much can't you set it to 5 seconds?" My read time 150000 milliseconds which is 2.5 minuts not 5 sec.

Comment: @Raghunandan "give me response immediate. what do you mean by that? " that mean i set an alert which give me status of my internet connectivity status real time.

Comment: i know. i said that ideally its should be 5 seconds not 15 seconds. If there is no read you get readtimeoutexception which you need to handle. there is nothing wrong with the code that i can see

Comment: yes there is nothing wrong in code but my concern is related response time why the s5 respond me after 2.5 minute

Comment: All you can do is reduce the time out to say 5 seconds. I don't have a samsung s5 phone. But  i don't think you can do much